# implementing a rudimentary scp

Tags: scp, openssh

I am planning to learn usage of the **openssh** library and have been thinking of implementing a rudimentary **scp** to help with the learning.

Where will I find the information that I will need to implement scp? I have tried going through the openssh documentation, but was wondering if there is an easier starting point for openssh beginners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can do so by watching `scp` do its work. Reading side does `scp -f <source>` and the writing side does `scp -t <target>`. If you interconnect them appropriately with FIFOs or so, you can see how exactly they interact.